# If I fit a water softener, will I run out of on-demand water via bath/shower-use?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-softener

I'm interested in fitting a water-softener (specifically, the [Twintec S3](http://www.twintec.com/water_softener/s3_blocksalt_softener), which is a dual-cylinder unit developed in the UK, apparently) to my home.  My home is over 3 stories, with a bathroom on the middle floor and an en-suite on the top floor.

The bathroom has a toilet, basin, and (large - 180cm x 80 cm) bath.  The en-suite has a shower, basin, and toilet.

Hot water is provided by a combi-boiler; I think it's an Ikon 23t or something similar to that.

I don't know the specific flow-rates of things, but...  if the water softener has 2 cylinders of 17 litres each, how will I **not** run out of water during long showers or filling up the bath?  This specific water-softener is supposed to regenerate in 10 minutes, and is supposed to be able to regenerate while the other cylinder is supplying.  But...  If a tap runs at 5l/min, and a cylinder holds 17l, then one cylinder will be drained after ~3m20s.  Then the other one will be too, shortly thereafter.

Am I missing something?  Do I have the cylinder-size wrong, or the regeneration-time...?

Comment: Impossible to answer w/o flow rates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Evil said impossible to tell you from the info you have provided, but if you look at the specs of the Twintec S3 it runs at 65l/m max flow rate and uses 17L per regeneration cycle ( eg wasted water)

Comment: Thanks; where did you find those specs?  I had a hunt for such things, but couldn't find them.  Perhaps I confused 17l per regeneration cycle with 17l per cylinder...?

Comment: http://www.twintec.com/water_softener/technical_specifications